# prove or disprove that every positive integer is the sum of a perfect square and a prime number or 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am absolutely clueless on how to prove this statement and what makes it more difficult is not knowing if it is true or false to try and find a way to prove it. Tried numbers up to 20 and it was true for all but that is not a proof that it is true for all integers. How do i go about answering this question?

Comment: hmmm. how did you come by this question?

Comment: I am going back through a course i took a few years back and solving every question in the book but i am stuck on this 1

Comment: What about 25??

Comment: mabye its square plus 0,1 or prime.

Comment: true for 25 = 36-11 = 6^2 - 11, IE SUM OF A perfect square and a prime

Comment: oh, the primes can be negative.

Comment: yes they did not put restriction for positive

Comment: does bunyakovsky imply this?

Comment: what about x=169?Ill be gone for a while, please don't downvote yet, I'll check comments in 4 hours. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: What was being discussed in the book in the chapter that includes this problem? What was the book?

Comment: I did find this problem in a set of lecture notes by Ulrich Meierfrankenfeld, at Michigan State. But I do not see it in the original book by Hungerford. So it is possible that Prof. Meierfrankenfeld put in this question after saying that primes were always positive for his course.

Comment: thanks will just saw the lecture notes you were talking about and saw that he based his notes on hungerfords book. he also allowed for pimes to be negative

Comment: I wish i knew if i was seeking to prove or disprove the statement.hmmm user, i am looking for 169 but still didnt find a pair of numbers one a perfect square and the other prime and i am having to go into large numbers. if 169 can be written as the sum of a perfect square and a prime number, the units digit must either be a 0 or a 6. ( all perfect squares unit digit end with 0, 1, 4, 5, 6 and 9 and with the other possibilities on the units digit, 169 - x^2 will not be prime.Tried with the smaller numbers couldnt find any but it might still be possible to find with larger numbers

Comment: okay i think i proved 169 is not the sum of a perfect square and a prime number.

Comment: 169 = 13^2 = x^2 + p, thus p = 13^2 - x^2 = (13-x)(13+x), thus for p to be prime 13 - x would have to equal 1 and x would have to equal 12 so that p = 13 + x = 25 which is not prime or 13 - x = -1 , x = 14 and 13 + 14 = 27 again p is not prime, so i do not see it possible for 169. Please critique my work or if you find something simpler, please comment. thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primes are positive.

So, 25 is not so expressible.  The sequence of non-expressible integers begins 25,34,58,64,85,91,121,130,169,196,214,289,324,... and is [A014090](http://oeis.org/A014090) at the OEIS.

There, Dean Hickerson gives a proof that this sequence is infinite.  Note that the allowance of the number 1 as an honorary prime does not cause difficulty, since a square cannot differ by 1 from a square.

Added: Dean's proof goes like this.  Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $2n-1$ is composite.  Then if we can write $n^2$ as the sum of a square and a prime, we'll have
$$ n^2 = m^2 + p$$ for some integer $m$ and some prime $p>0$.  Then, 
$$ p = n^2-m^2 = (n-m)(n+m).$$  Since $p$ is prime, we must have 
$$ n-m=1$$
and so $p=n+m=2n-1$, which contradicts the primality of $p$.  So $n^2$ is not so representable.

Now, if we allow negative primes, we simply modify this and consider positive $n$ such that $2n-1$ and $2n+1$ are composite.  Then if $n^2=m^2+p$ for some integer $m$ and some prime $p$, possibly negative, we have
$$ p =n^2-m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$$ and so $n-m=\pm 1$ and $n+m=2n+1$ or $n+m=2n-1$.  Since both values are composite, this contradicts $p$'s primality.  So $n^2$ is not so representable.

Now, there are infinitely many such $n$. Consider, for example, $n$ of the form 
$$ n = 13+15r$$ for $r$ a positive integer.  Then
$$ 2n-1 = 25+30r = 5(5+6r)$$
and
$$2n+1 = 27+30r = 3(9+10r)$$
are both composite, and so there are infinitely many integers not representable as the sum of a square and a prime (positive or negative).

Comment: not according to the text i am using hungerford, he is defining a prime number to be an integer other than 1 or -1 whose only devisors are p, -p, 1, -1

Comment: How odd. This breaks unique factorization, among other things.

Comment: I did find this problem in a set of lecture notes by Ulrich Meierfrankenfeld, at Michigan State. But I do not see it in the original book by Hungerford. So it is possible that Prof. Meierfrankenfeld put in this question after saying that primes were always positive for his course.

Comment: i dont think that this breaks unique factorisation because he does say that every number can be written uniquely as a product of positive primes

Comment: it is on page 18 question 24 in hungerford so supposedly a beginning problem

Comment: @george, possibly in an early edition. In the third edition the problems start at page 22.

Comment: thank you mathew for introducing me to oeis, did not know such a thing existed, its amazing. however, that sequence considers primes as positive numbers. will the outcome be different if primes were also allowed to be their opposites

Comment: @george I've added the proof and included negative primes.  Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much mathew, very nice. i have actually seen a solution following users hint can you please check my work, it is under the comments by user

Comment: here it is again for easy reference:

Comment: 169 = 13^2 = x^2 + p, thus p = 13^2 - x^2 = (13-x)(13+x), thus for p to be prime 13 - x would have to equal 1 and x would have to equal 12 so that p = 13 + x = 25 which is not prime or 13 - x = -1 , x = 14 and 13 + 14 = 27 again p is not prime, so i do not see it possible for 169. Please critique my work or if you find something simpler, please comment. thanks for everyones help . but mathew yours is a more general proof