# Proof or disproof that every integer can be written as the sum of a prime and a square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm refreshing some algebra and in the beginning chapters of my book I'm presented with the following simple looking problem that I got stuck on:

> Prove or disprove: If $n$ is a positive integer, then $n=p+a^2$, where $a$ is an integer and $p$ is prime or $p=1$.

At first I thought $n=13$ would give a nice counterexample, but then I noticed my book defines primes to include the negative primes. Now $13=-3+4^2$ is a solution.

I am allowed to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and the division and euclidean algorithms. I tried to express $n$ and $a$ by their prime factorizations, but I didn't get anywhere from there. I would like a hint which direction to take. Am I just missing something silly?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613256/prove-or-disprove-that-every-positive-integer-is-the-sum-of-a-perfect-square-and.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $n=169$. The number $169-a^2$ factors as $(13-a)(13+a)$. Can one of these factors be $\pm 1$ and the other "prime"? The possibilities are $a=\pm 12$ and $a=\pm 14$, and they don't work.

Comment: Ahh of course! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. The strategy of looking for perfect squares $n$ is to make factorization "likely." There probably are examples smaller than $169$, but for non-squares the arithmetic would be more tedious.